# Ukrainian equivalent of 'Nothing of value was lost'?

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

I wanted to know how can you express this in Ukrainian and if Ukrainian has an equivalent phrase.

General explanation in my own words: Phrase is used in situations when something went bad and at first glance the situation looks dire, however for the narrator this is actually a good riddance.

Context and uses:

A server disk is broken and we can't recover any data from it. It was a RAID0 and we have no backups. But then comes a lead and says: You know, we wanted to decomission that server for a while now and this kinda just forces the inevitable. Nothing of value was lost with the loss of this server.

- Hey did you know? The website with lots of horny women from your area is closed!
- So what? Nothing of value was lost.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about translation must include: (1) rough explanation of the meaning **in your own words** — especially when it comes about **idioms and phraseologisms**; (2) **context**, in which the OP is going to use the word/phrase; (3) show the OP's own attempt to find the answer, and (4) explain why the answers you found so far do not satisfy your request.

Comment: deimos, could you please provide examples when such a phrase is used? @bytebuster, while I agree with your opinion that the question should be improved, I personally think that it would be much more friendly to users if we express it in the way "this question should be improved because of that and that" rather than "this question is bad because of that and that". A newcomer often simply doesn't know requirements for questions (that we implicitly request), and when they are stated in such way he might understand that as "you're not welcome" rather than "welcome, but pls extend your question".

Comment: I think the phrase happens to be used when something *bad* happened but *nothing of value was lost*. For example somebody has died, but *nothing of value was lost* because nobody liked that guy.

Comment: I can't say I appreciate your hostility, but I added some context and explanation to the topic. @Yola is also correct.

Comment: @Sasha, there was nothing in my comment like *"…is bad because…"* (as well as like ""…should be improved because…""). The *"I'm voting to close because…"* is the standard beginning of closure reason hard-coded into Review Queues of Stack Exchange, and I feel a bit awkward telling this to someone who should know how Review works. :-)

Comment: @bytebuster, a newcomer doesn't know that. IMHO, a newcomer can interpret that as "you're not welcome". Every post of every newcomer is surrounded by "Xxx is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct" not without a purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the meaning of the English phrase correctly, I can suggest the following variants:

- "Нічого страшного" (literally —  "[there's] nothing terrible [in that]"). E.g.:

  > — Нічого страшного, — сказав один з них, — черепок цілий, — і навернув Тимкові на голові білу чалму. //Hryhir Tiutiunnyk, "Вир" ("The Whirlpool").
- "Ну то й що?" (literally — "and what then"). Usually is used to emphasize that nothing really serious happened. E.g.:

  > Він ішов лісовою дорогою із радюжкою з травою за плечима, яку підтримував рукою, у другій ніс косу й раптом явно відчув — йому хочеться оглянутися. Оглянутися, бо там хтось є, за ним хтось йде.
  >
  > «Ну то й що? — подумав. — Разом ітимемо». //Volodymyr Lys, "Діва Млинища" ("The Virgin of Mlynyshche").
- ["Велике діло!"](https://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2158-velyke-dilo.html) (literally — "a great/large case/issue/thing"). Often is used in sarcastic manner to express that the discussed thing is really *not* serious. E.g.:

  > А щука на своє хилила: «Ет, вигадки! Велике діло — миші». //Leonid Hlibov, "Щука й Кіт" ("Esox/Pike and Cat").
- "Теж мені проблема" (literally — "[that's] one more problem for me"). Almost always used in sarcastic manner, expressing that something is really *not* a problem ("теж мені " usually has such an inverted/sarcastic meaning). E.g.:

  > — Два екзамени в один день — теж мені проблема, скажи, Дживс? — прошепотіла вона, згортаючись клубочком. //Nadiya Herbish, "Домо-над-морем-терапія" ("House-over-the-sea-therapy").

Comment: > Almost always used in sarcastic manner, expressing that something is really not a problem.

That sounds about right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So, I think you are looking for a phrase "**Коли б тільки й горя**" or in other words "**Якби тільки й лиха**" ([Ukrainian phrase dictionary](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53393/356081.html)). We, Ukrainians, use it to calm down a person and show them that they shouldn't worry about this or that problem, because it's just a matter of small weight.

However, I'd translate this phrase as "**Нічого страшного**". Also, we have a phrase "**Не біда**" ([Ukrainian dictionary](http://sum.in.ua/s/bida)).

Comment: Do they convey the same sarcastic meaning or is it just an expression of sympathy? The 'Nothing of value was lost' means 'It's lost? Good. About time'. There is no sympathy in it.

Comment: There is sympathy in "коли б тільки й горя", it means "it's bad, but don't worry, it's not that bad".